# Track websites hotlink my images

Tags: php, html

I allow visitors to copy an HTML snippet into their own websites which includes an image hosted on my website.

What is the best way to track websites that are hotlinking these images?

I was thinking of creating a webpage like `getImage.php?imageID=12345` and using that as the image src in my code snippet, but how would I get which website is using this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the website linking your image can be found via `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Comment: Didn't realise this was sent through when requesting images using the PHP method, but it is! It's REFERER though, not REFERRER. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I always make that mistake.